# Do I want to join/merge, concat, or append these two Pandas DataFrames?

Tags: python, pandas

How would I paste these two tables together using join/merge/concat/append/add in such a way that the population age 0-14, and 15-64 columns are side-by-side?

I don't need the *cartesian product* of these two DataFrames.

I've tried:

```
population ages = t3.merge(t4, on='Country Name', how='inner')
```

**t3**

```
  Country Name  Year  Population Age 0 - 14
0        Aruba  1960              43.847771
1      Andorra  1960                    NaN
2  Afghanistan  1960              43.712284
3       Angola  1960              43.759289
4      Albania  1960              41.757282
```

**t4**

```
  Country Name  Population Age 15 - 64
0        Aruba               53.667355
1      Andorra                     NaN
2  Afghanistan               53.834637
3       Angola               53.587101
4      Albania               52.941044
```

**Ideally**

```
  Country Name  Population Age 15 - 64  Population Ages 0 - 14 
0        Aruba               53.667355               43.847771
1      Andorra                     NaN                     NaN
2  Afghanistan               53.834637               43.712284
3       Angola               53.587101               43.759289
4      Albania               52.941044               41.757282
```

---

**Test results:**

```
population_ages = t3.merge(t4, on='Country Name', how='inner')
```

I received a DataFrame that's a cartesian product of t3, t4 with a shape of (734832, 4) instead of (13608, 4)

```
       Country Name  Year  Population Age 0 - 14  Population Age 15 - 64
0             Aruba  1960              43.847771               53.667355
1             Aruba  1960              43.847771               53.890141
2             Aruba  1960              43.847771               54.216911
3             Aruba  1960              43.847771               54.637810
4             Aruba  1960              43.847771               55.119324
5             Aruba  1960              43.847771               55.631104
6             Aruba  1960              43.847771               56.168560
7             Aruba  1960              43.847771               56.736549
8             Aruba  1960              43.847771               57.341782
9             Aruba  1960              43.847771               57.983109
10            Aruba  1960              43.847771               58.674343
11            Aruba  1960              43.847771               59.404758
12            Aruba  1960              43.847771               60.164749
```

Comment: And what you get ? What did you expect ?

Comment: I received a DataFrame that's a cartesian product of t3, t4 with a shape of (734832, 4) instead of (13608, 4)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about

```
t4['Population Age 0 - 14'] = t3['Population Age 0 - 14']
```

or

```
pd.concat( t4, t3['Population Age 0 - 14'], axis=1)
```

full working example:

```
import pandas as pd
from StringIO import StringIO

d1 = '''Country Name  Year  Population Age 0 - 14
        Aruba  1960              43.847771
      Andorra  1960                    NaN
  Afghanistan  1960              43.712284
       Angola  1960              43.759289
      Albania  1960              41.757282'''

d2 = '''Country Name  Population Age 15 - 64
        Aruba               53.667355
      Andorra                     NaN
  Afghanistan               53.834637
       Angola               53.587101
      Albania               52.941044'''

t3 = pd.DataFrame.from_csv( StringIO(d1), sep='\s{2,}', index_col=None )
print '\nt3:\n',t3

t4 = pd.DataFrame.from_csv( StringIO(d2), sep='\s{2,}', index_col=None )
print '\nt4:\n',t3

print '\n--- merge ---\n'

print pd.merge( t4, t3, on='Country Name')

print pd.merge( t4, t3[ ['Country Name', 'Population Age 0 - 14'] ], on='Country Name')

print '\n--- concat ---\n'

print pd.concat( (t4, t3['Population Age 0 - 14']), axis=1)

print '\n--- [xxx] = [xxx] ---\n'

t4['Population Age 0 - 14'] = t3['Population Age 0 - 14']

print t4
```

result:

```
  Country Name  Population Age 15 - 64  Population Age 0 - 14
0        Aruba               53.667355              43.847771
1      Andorra                     NaN                    NaN
2  Afghanistan               53.834637              43.712284
3       Angola               53.587101              43.759289
4      Albania               52.941044              41.757282
```

Comment: That did it, thanks! I'll have to read the docs some more - I'd tried a similar method, but it just wasn't working.

Comment: This versions have one minus - they don't check `Country Name` during merging/joining. So you can get unexpected result if there are no some countries in one of column.

Comment: BTW: I tried `pd.merge( t4, t3, on='Country Name')` and I got expected result too. I add it to working example.

Comment: `pd.merge( t4, t3[ ['Country Name', 'Population Age 0 - 14'] ], on='Country Name')` works too - and it gets rid of column `Year`.